# Stored procodure in table query show daily data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I created the structure where users send requests in the SOAP (asmx) web service as a stored procedure. Users are asked for the following values:

```
Device id (string)
Start date (datetime)
End date (datetime)
```

A row is returned for each day among the dates entered here. For example, if you entered January 1 to January 5, a total of 5 rows will return the data of that device for each separate day. Hours can be entered here, so the end of the day is always 23:59:59. I would especially like to point out that specific data such as 1 January 10:00 to 1 January 13:00 can also be entered.

I record this date and what the device did during that day numerically in a table, there is no problem, but I am having trouble displaying it with select.

Sample tables where records are added and belong to a device;

[image]

Since the same query was made several times, these are also recorded, so it shows this. My goal is to return as many records as the day difference between the recorded dates in a way that does not repeat.

The query I use for this is this:

```
SELECT TOP (@dayDiff) DISTINCT 
    DEVICE, VALUE, DATE, DATE1 
FROM
    tableName 
WHERE 
    DEVICE = @DeviceId 
    AND DATE1 >= @Date1 
    AND DATE2 <= @Date1 
    AND ABS(VALUE) >= 0 
ORDER BY 
    [DATE1] ASC
```

I call this stored procedure;

```
EXEC [dbo].[exampleProcedure] 'ABC','2023-12-25 12:00:00','2024-01-04 15:00:00'
```

This query result show;

[image]

I want this result by stored procedure so every day one show by row

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Please make sure you do not uses images - use tabular text

Comment: I added the procedure call and output result to the question, but I could not manage to add the table structure without the photo, it appears as a photo.

Comment: So what about this help didn't make sense https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Once you remove those images you'll have a good question

Comment: You can use calendar table and take dates from ``Date1`` to ``Date+dayDiff``, then join with subquery from ``tableName``

Answer (score 0):

A date dimension is a very handy thing to take advantage of (data warehousing).

However, for general use, there is a quick and dirty way to create a virtual "date dimension" on the fly through a recursive ctde:

```
declare @start datetime, @end datetime
set @start = '20240101'
set @end = '20240105'
;
with daterange as 
(
   select @start 'Date', 1 'Record'
   union all
   select dateadd(day,1,Date), Record + 1
   from daterange
   where dateadd(day,1,@start) <= @end
   and Record < datediff(day, @start, @end) + 1
)
select *
from daterange
```

You can then join daterange as part of your subsequent query and group by Date etc.